# eBPFのサンプルコード実行時に Argument list too long

Tags: python, linux, c, security

## 現環境

eBPFの環境構築を以下のページを参考にして、動かしています。

[ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS でeBPFをインストール](https://qiita.com/hayama17/items/d06d11c47f1803cc9e1d)

```
uname -a
Linux *** 5.4.0-156-generic #173-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 11 07:25:22 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

## 困っていること

参照したページに掲載のコードを以下の通り実行するとエラーが出てきます。
少し変えて動かしたり、他のコードを動かしても同じようなエラーが出てしまいます。

**実行結果:**

```
$ sudo -E python3 hello_world.py
bpf: Argument list too long. Program  too large (0 insns), at most 4096 insns

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello_world.py", line 18, in <module>
    b.attach_kprobe(event=b.get_syscall_fnname("clone"), fn_name="hello")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bcc-0.28.0+173282d3-py3.8.egg/bcc/__init__.py", line 851, in attach_kprobe
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bcc-0.28.0+173282d3-py3.8.egg/bcc/__init__.py", line 526, in load_func
Exception: Failed to load BPF program b'hello': Argument list too long
```

エラーの内容も以下の通りで意味不明なので、どうすればいいのかわかりません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
Argument list too long. Program  too large (0 insns), at most 4096 insns
```

**実行したコード:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# This is a Hello World example that formats output as fields.

from bcc import BPF
from bcc.utils import printb

# define BPF program
prog = """
int hello(void *ctx) {
    bpf_trace_printk("Hello, World!\\n");
    return 0;
}
"""

# load BPF program
b = BPF(text=prog)
b.attach_kprobe(event=b.get_syscall_fnname("clone"), fn_name="hello")

# header
print("%-18s %-16s %-6s %s" % ("TIME(s)", "COMM", "PID", "MESSAGE"))

# format output
while 1:
    try:
        (task, pid, cpu, flags, ts, msg) = b.trace_fields()
    except ValueError:
        continue
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
    printb(b"%-18.9f %-16s %-6d %s" % (ts, task, pid, msg))
```